# How to merge and sum up fields based on 2 columns

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, awk, perl

I have a file as follows:

```
Bitrate        ASNUM       TotalBytes    DownloadTime   NumberCount

280000          2856        61454           12

280000          2856        61428           14

1179968         2856        309430          11

1179968         4156        309200          15

4864960         2856        997962          193 

4864960         2856        1115576         300

4864960         2856        997962          116
```

I need to merge the lines based on the 1st 2 columns i.e. Bitrate and ASNUM and add up the Total Bytes and DownloadTimes fields corresponding to them.

The resulting output should be as follows:

```
Bitrate        ASNUM      TotalBytes     DownloadTime   NumberCount 

280000          2856        122882          26               2  

1179968         2856        309430          11               1

1179968         4156        309200          15               1

4864960         2856        3111500         609              3
```

where the additional column NumberCount indicates the number of occurences.

Could you please help with the code I can implement to get this working?

Comment: [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is made for this kind of thing

Comment: And awk can do this job too!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution using awk:

```
awk -F " " '
    NR==1 {print; next} 
    NF {a[$1" "$2]+=$3; b[$1" "$2]+=$4; c[$1" "$2]++} 
    END {for(i in a)print i, a[i], b[i], c[i]}
' file
```

--> inputFile should be in the directory where you are running the command

--> -F " " considers a single space as the delimiter

--> NR==1{print;next} prints the headers to output and skips it

--> array a[$1" "$2] considers group by of 1st column value and 2nd column value. Same for array b and c.

--> += operator sums up the required column based on the group by of array

--> ++ operator used with array c stores the count on the group by

--> Last "for" loop is used to print the results to output

Answer (score 1):

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Overview.html#Overview) is made for this kind of task - for example

```
datamash -WH -g 1,2 sum 3,4 count 4
```

or more verbosely

```
datamash --whitespace --headers \
  groupby Bitrate,ASNUM sum TotalBytes,DownloadTime count DownloadTime
```

(it doesn't matter which of the non-grouped fields you specify for the `count`).

Your case is complicated slightly by the blank lines - but you can simply strip them out before and re-add them after e.g.

```
sed '/^$/d' file | datamash -WH -g 1,2 sum 3,4 count 4 | column -t | sed G
GroupBy(Bitrate)  GroupBy(ASNUM)  sum(TotalBytes)  sum(DownloadTime)  count(DownloadTime)

280000            2856            122882           26                 2

1179968           2856            309430           11                 1

1179968           4156            309200           15                 1

4864960           2856            3111500          609                3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well on the local system, however it is not supported on the server where I am trying to perform this action, and can neither be installed due to restrictions. Any chance you could help with an equivalent SQL code or anything of that sort?

Comment: @ShravanAlva if the original data is the result of a database query then certainly the best option would be to modify that (it's probably a matter of adding an appropriate `GROUP BY` and the required sums / counts). However as a programming question it would be better to ask on [so]. If that's not an option then it would certainly be possible to implement the same functionality as `datamash` in `awk` or `perl`.